# Does `sp_spaceused` calculate columns that contain image in a table?

Tags: sybase

there is a table that have few rows however contain several iamges, and I want to know there size , does spaceused gives the right size ?

Does `sp_spaceused` calculate columns that contain image in a table ?

example:

```
sp_spaceused tab1
```

will gives

```
name  rowtotal reserved   data   index_size   unused
tab1   153390   6436832   8248   63270576    79528
```

this table structure contain image data . so what is the size of the table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `sp_help table_name` Reports information about a database object (any object listed in sysobjects) and about system or user-defined datatypes. Column displays optimistic_index_lock.
2. Use `sp_spaceused [objname [,1] ]`,That reports the table and each index separately. Dividing the data space used by the row-total will give you one value for the actual row length (not counting fragmentation, which is based on the lock scheme and activity).

   - data   : in use for table/data storage
   - index  : in use by indexes or text/image chains
   - unused : space reserved for object usage but which hasn't yet been used

[Official source that information was taken](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/X50477.htm)

Comment: I guess sp_spaceused is the better then sp_help . btw why do use 1 next to table ?